# AngularJS splitter example

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am really new to AngularJS. I am trying to change the layout of an existing application. The layout I am trying to achieve is this.

[image]

I have found this example

[Sample layout from online research](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zi2f0EPxmtEUmdoFR63B?p=preview&preview)

Excerpt from Pluker

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" data-semver="2.0.3" data-require="jquery"></script>
    <script data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="resizer.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div id="topnav">Top navbar</div>
  
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h3>Side navbar</h3>
    </div>
  
    <div id="content">

        <div id="top-content">Top content <p>{{content}}</p></div>
  
        <div id="bottom-content">Bottom content</div>
  
        <div id="content-resizer" 
            resizer="horizontal" 
            resizer-height="6" 
            resizer-top="#top-content" 
            resizer-bottom="#bottom-content">
        </div>
  
    </div>
  
    <div id="sidebar-resizer" 
        resizer="vertical" 
        resizer-width="6" 
        resizer-left="#sidebar" 
        resizer-right="#content"
        resizer-max="400">
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Can anyone help me to modify this layout to match my layout.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd also suggest - if this is a new project - that you use Angular rather than AngularJs since Angular is the newer one.

Comment: I understand. Thank you but as I mentioned in my question, it is an existing application.

Comment: Understood. I know that pain! :)